# Is it possible to have an element be the exact same size on all devices?

Tags: css

I am currently using `css: {width: 63mm;}` but it is not 63mm most of the time at all. I am wanting to generate some playing cards that will be life sized on all devices, phones included but it still seems to scale. I need to know if there is a measurement available to fix this or am I going to have to accept that it is not possible / reasonable.

EDIT: if you need information on the code, here is my site: http://lano-project.org/update/downloads/

Comment: can you provide an codepen highlighting the issue, if you set `width:63mm` it wont change based on window size, so the question is not very clear.

Comment: I just added a link.

Comment: so what you wana do with that cards

Comment: the card dimensions do not change based on the screen size, do you want to remove the cards adjusting automatically on screen size change?

Comment: I don't think you can feasibly guarantee this across all devices, as even different devices in the same device category (e.g. smartphone) come in a variety of display resolutions that would result in 1-5mm differences.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to expect the exact same real-life units on the screen.

It's not recommended [to use such units hen targeting screens in CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html). They are meant for use in `@media print` queries, when specifying the stylesheet for printing purposes.

From the linked article above (emphasis mine):

> The so-called absolute units (cm, mm, in, pt and pc) mean the same in CSS as everywhere else, but **only if your output device has a high enough resolution**. On a laser printer, 1cm should be exactly 1 centimeter. But **on low-resolution devices**, such as computer screens, **CSS doesn't require that**. And indeed, the result tends to be different from one device to another and from one CSS implementation to another. It's better to reserve these units for high-resolution devices and in particular for printed output. On computer screens and handheld devices, you'll **probably not get what you expect**.

Comment: So if I print out the cards they will be perfect sizes no matter what device. It is mildly disappointing that there is not really a way to fix the on screen size but it is understandable.

Comment: It makes sense: why would you want 43mm on a 50" TV screen and a smartwatch? Instead, set the base font size for TV screen to be 40px and for smartwatch to be 10px and then scale your cards according to font-size. Your cards will maintain proper aspect-ratio, and will be scaled along with the font-size used inside. More info in the article I linked in the answer.